# why did the raw_input fail?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I am coming up with stock ticker program and the program asks the user to enter a symbol but the `raw_input` fails. And I am scraping yahoo finance. And this is the code: thanks a tons!!!

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
symbol = raw_input("enter a stock")
def get_all_info():
  i = 0
  while i < len(list):
        url = urllib2.urlopen("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + symbol[i] + "&ql=0")
        soup = bs4(url,"html.parser")
        for price in soup.find(attrs={'id':"yfs_l84_" + symbol[i]}):               
        print "real time price: " + price
        i += 1
 print get_all_info()
```

and this is the error:

```
  traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Raunaq/PycharmProjects/stock_market_work/ask.py", line 18, in      <module>
    print get_all_info()
  File "C:/Users/Raunaq/PycharmProjects/stock_market_work/ask.py", line 14, in get_all_info
    for price in soup.find(attrs={'id':"yfs_l84_" + name[i]}):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out you need to enter a list of stock names and print out their costs with scraping yahoo finance through BeautifulSoup, if so here is the complete code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

def get_all_info():
    i = 0
    while i < len(list1):
        url = urllib2.urlopen("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + list1[i] + "&ql=0")
        soup = bs4(url,"html.parser")
        price = soup.find(attrs={'id':"yfs_l84_" + list1[i]})
        if price:     
            print ("real time price (for {0}): {1}".format(list1[i],price.contents[0]))
        i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stocks = raw_input("enter stocks names (space separated): ")
    list1 = stocks.split()
    get_all_info()
```

Run:

> python script_name.py
>
> enter stocks names (space separated): yhoo goog
>
> real time price (for yhoo): 35.07
>
> real time price (for goog): 728.11

Comment: It's just string.format instead of string concatination

Comment: @Beyond Prithvi :  If the answer is correct, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick sign near it

Comment: hi! how does python know that ("real time price (for {0}): {1}" 0 is the name for the stock?

Comment: @BeyondPrithvi :  It's sequence, 0 for first arguemnt, 1 for second, you can even use {} without numbers